# Can I have template parts with a straight HTML/CSS website?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out if it is even possible to somehow implement 'template sections' with a straight html/css website. I use template parts all the time when building wordpress themes, but not sure if there is a way to implement a template section w/out php.

Can anyone offer some advice on this? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can technically have "template" parts by copying and pasting the code from one page to another. So I guess that isn't what you would want to do.

So you are correct, in that you would need something like PHP for this. To set up some basic PHP is not that hard. It really will save a lot of needless code and time, by at least using PHP for your header and footer, if they will be the same on all pages.

Comment: Yes, you will need a web-framework that does pre-processing of the HTML, etc, on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any links to where I can read about implementing something like that on a basic html/css website? That is really the only PHP I would need and early don't want to build a huge WP theme just to use section templates.